# .not(this) on jQuery still identifies this(current row selected) why is that?

Tags: jquery, html

*I have a table of data and i have an icon on the last td per tr which has class of icon-size and edit i wish to highlight a certain row whenever it is selected(emphasis-border). I also would want to remove it whenever i click the icon again or click other edit icons I am aware already of the toggleClass and removeClass of jquery but its still not working*

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
                    @for(item <- form.get().emplist) {
                <tr>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.employeeId</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.firstName</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.lastName</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.email</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.phoneNo</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">
                        <div class="position-relative">
                        <span class="class-hiredate">@item.displayHiredate</span>
                        <input type="image" src="/assets/images/imgDate.jpg" class="icon-size date">
                        </div></td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.job.jobTitle</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.displaySalary</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.commission</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.deptName</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content">@item.managerName</td>
                    <td class="solid-green-border column-content"><input type="image" src="@routes.Assets.at("images/Edit.jpg")" class="icon-size edit"></td>
                </tr>
                    }
            </tbody>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-size.edit', function(){
$('.icon-size.edit').closest('tr').find('td').not(this).removeClass('emphasis-border');
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').toggleClass('emphasis-border');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.emphasis-border {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: rgb(255,215,0);
}
```

Comment: I'm using play framework in eclipse so i cant pretty much simply copy paste my table,im very sorry for that but i can show my table structure,,ill edit my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event is on the input, so `this` is the input, not the `td`.
You can do it like this -

```
var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
$('.icon-size.edit').closest('tr').find('tr').not(parent).find('td').removeClass('emphasis-border');
parent.find('td').toggleClass('emphasis-border');
```

Comment: i am grateful for the suggested answer but its not working,specifically the td with the edit icon is the only one having emphasis border and also if i click it again it does not remove it

Comment: already working i only changed your parent a little bit with var parent = $(this).closest('tr').find('td'); thanks again,, i really appreciate your help :)